# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id' во Flask

Tags: python, flask, атрибуты

models.py

```py
def slugify(s):
    pattern = r'[^\w+]'
    return re.sub(pattern, '-', s).lower()

class Company(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    ynp = db.Column(db.String(20))
    comment = db.Column(db.Text, default='')
    bank_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    bank_account = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    slug = db.Column(db.String(140), unique=True)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
    contry = db.Column(db.String(50), default='дом')
    contacts = db.relationship('Contact', backref='cont', lazy=True)



    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Company, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.generate_slug()

    def generate_slug(self):
        if self.name:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)


class Contact(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    comment = db.Column(db.Text, default='')
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    slug = db.Column(db.String(140), unique=True)
    position = db.Column(db.String(100))
    company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Contact, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.generate_slug()

    def generate_slug(self):
        if self.name:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
```

views.py

```py
@app.route('/<slug>')
def company_detail(slug):
    detail = Company.query.filter(Company.slug == slug).first()
        # contact = Contact.query.filter(Contact.company_id == detail.id).all()
    contact = Contact.query.filter(Contact.company_id == detail.id).all()
    # contact = Contact.query.all()
    return render_template('/company_detail.html', detail=detail, contact=contact)
```

Импортирую в карточку компании все контакты с ID компании и появляется исключение

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Ну значит иногда поиск по `slug` ничего не находит и в `detail` находится `None`. Проверяйте это и делайте что-то другое в таком случае, вместо того, чтобы не глядя использовать дальше `detail.id`

Comment: почему тогда в HTML я получаю id через {{ detail.id }}                    #  id-----------{{ detail.id }}